# Как скачать видео aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

Имею хэндлер:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["video"])
```

Как через него сохранить видео, которое поступит на вход?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я использую такой подход

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["video"])
async def download_video(message: types.Message):
    file_id = message.video.file_id # Get file id
    file = await bot.get_file(file_id) # Get file path
    await bot.download_file(file.file_path, "video.mp4") # Download video and save output in file "video.mp4"
```

Сначала мы получаем id видео файла, после получаем путь к файлу, и уже потом сохраняем результат в файл `video.mp4` 
Важно знать что формат MP4 является стандартным для телеграма, в других форматах лучше не пробовать сохранять.

Если вы не хотите перезаписывать файл после каждой загрузки видео, попробуйте этот код, есть решения элегантнее, но это в самый раз на скорую руку.

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["video"])
async def download_video(message: types.Message):
    file_id = message.video.file_id # Get file id
    file = await bot.get_file(file_id) # Get file path
    video_number = 0 # Number video file
    while(os.path.isfile(f"video{video_number}.mp4")): # If the file exists, add one to the number
        video_number += 1 
    await bot.download_file(file.file_path, f"video{video_number}.mp4") # Download video and save output in file "video.mp4"
```

А привязать конкретный видеофайл к конкретному пользователю вам поможет база данных. В ней вы можете связать id файла, с пользовательским id.
И когда необходимо взаимодействовать с этими данными.

[Документация aiogram (загрузка файлов)](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/download_file.html)

Comment: @ClarkDevlin для этого я проверяю существует ли файл с номером 0 и выше, если существует мы добавляем +1 к номеру, и опять проверяем. Решение не лучшее, но может быстро выручить. И от того что переменная сбросилась после очередного вызова функции, ничего не зависит. Советую перечитать мой код.

Comment: Ну да, не увидел, а зачем каждый раз стопарить всего бота вайлом? Это крайне плохое решение, не проще ли получать текущую дату и время и это использовать в виде названия?